# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder

Tags: java

We are seeing an error when trying to invoke a getreports operation in an application. It is running inside a java 6 environment. Please let me know if I need to add in more details.

```
                       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:269)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:598)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:557)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:542)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:439)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:444)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:129)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:160)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:75)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1694)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:970)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:878)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:278)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
```

Comment: Is this an IBM JVM? Domino or Notes?

Comment: It is  an IBM JVM running in Websphere

Answer (score 0):

Include jaxws-rt-x.x.x (where x.x.x is the version number of the jaxws library) in your classpath. The latest is jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar.

Include any other additional dependencies that are needed in your classpath.

Comment: That is strange, is it there in the runtime classpath? I mean, you could have had it in your classpath while compiling your application. But is Websphere loading the jax rt library in its shared or application specific runtime classpath?

Comment: Yes Chetan, it was in the runtime classpath. I Was using the class loading detection with in WebSphere to check that .